# What are the best SEO practices regarding multiple versions of HTML elements(mobile, desktop) in a Vue application?

Tags: vue.js, responsive-design, seo

So currently, I am using `hidden-mobile` and `hidden-desktop` css classes to display different variants of elements based on the screen size.
But there are problems with the HTML structure that negatively affects SEO as result of this, where I am having duplicate content, multiple <h1> tags, etc.

What I am wondering is what are the best practices for this.

Right now the only thing I can think of is creating some sort of re-usable file that allows me to use computed values such as `isMobile` and `isDesktop`, where I could render these elements conditionally with a `v-if` directive.

The problem is that I am unsure about this approach and worried about potential performance issues, etc.
I just cannot seem to find any resources on this topic about the best practices.

I would like to hear your opinion or if you could provide some resources about this, I would be very grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ . If it's a website then it's irrelevant to vue. If you can physically remove an element that affects SEO then do it. If it's v-if in your case then that's it. If your SO-specific question is whether the use of v-if on rarely updated value can affect the performance to the point it's undesirable to use it then the answer is no.